# Send notification when new results uploaded on a website

Tags: android, ios, python-3.x, web

I am looking to send a notification when a change occurs to results on a website. I am scraping a website and getting the data so I need to send the notification with the content of the change when the data changes.
For example I have the data in excel and when a new line is added I send a notification telling what that data is

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Google Cloud Messaging service. It's simple, you can handle difference on your server, then send JSON with data what you need to show in app and your handlers in applications will receive it.

for more details visit: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/